# How do i can track all my own transactions in ripple.Whether any user is submitting or withdrawing ripple

Tags: transactions, ripple, ripple-api

Thanks in advance.

I have one fixed address on ripple and user will be submitting and withdrawing ripple currency in my site.

I need to track all the transaction happening with all my users.

Please tell me the better way to handle such problem.

There is an API https://ripple.com/build/data-api-v2/#get-transactions which will give all the transaction in the descending order.

But I am unable to track transaction which is occurring to my users only.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use an api, then there are few methods you could use as:

[Get Account Transaction History](https://ripple.com/build/data-api-v2/#get-account-transaction-history)

[Get Account Payments](https://ripple.com/build/data-api-v2/#get-account-payments)

[Get Transaction By Account And Sequence](https://ripple.com/build/data-api-v2/#get-transaction-by-account-and-sequence)

Also, you could use [Ripple accounts explorer](https://bithomp.com/explorer/) to check your account history with user interface.